# Is there a way to crop a model in THREE.JS?

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to crop a model in THREE.JS?

For example I have this model:

[image]

And know I want to cut him from the belt and down, like this:

[image]

Is there a way?

Maybe create a cube and position it to cover the legs, and then somehow remove all parts of the model that's intersect with the cube...

thanks.

[update]

I think I found a solution that suits me,

I would like to improve it and replace PointInsideBBOX to check if a vertex or a face is collide or inside a second mesh, any idea?

This solution is better for me because all the textures and skeletal animation works perfect.

```html
mesh.material.materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({visible: false}));
var matIndex =  mesh.material.materials.length - 1; 

function PointInsideBBOX(point,box) {
 if (  
  point.x>=box.x1 && point.x<=box.x2 && 
  point.y>=box.y1 && point.y<=box.y2 &&
  point.z>=box.z1 && point.z<=box.z2 
  ) return true;
 return false;
 }

var box = {
 x1: -0.25 , y1: -0.5 , z1: -0.25 ,
 x2: 0.25 , y2: 0.5 , z2: 0.25 ,
 };
 
for(var i=0; i<mesh.geometry.faces.length; i++) {
 var face = mesh.geometry.faces[i];
 if ( !PointInsideBBOX(mesh.geometry.vertices[face.a],box) ||
   !PointInsideBBOX(mesh.geometry.vertices[face.b],box) ||
   !PointInsideBBOX(mesh.geometry.vertices[face.c],box)
  ) continue; 
 face.materialIndex = matIndex;
 }
 
mesh.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this project https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG

```
var cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,10);
var cube_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry);
cube_mesh.position.x = x;
cube_mesh.position.y = 0; //y;
cube_mesh.position.z = z;

var CutBSP = new ThreeBSP(cube_mesh);
var ModelBSP = new ThreeBSP(mesh); //<---- your THREE Mesh
var EditiedBSP = ModelBSP.subtract(CutBSP);

var result = EditiedBSP.toMesh(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({shading: THREE.SmoothShading}));
result.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
mesh.geometry = result.geometry; //<---- your NEW Geometry
```